# tlmgr didn't install packages after self update on windows 10

Tags: windows, tlmgr, update

I have a problem to install package. I found that I need to install [update-tlmgr-latest.exe](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe) and the it will work but not. If I try to `tlmgr install polski` I had:

```
tlmgr itself needs to be updated.
Please do this via either
  tlmgr update --self
or by getting the latest updater for Unix-ish systems:
  https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
and/or Windows systems:
  https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe
Then continue with other updates as usual.
```

**Could somebody help me with it?**

```
tlmgr revision 63068 (2022-04-18 07:58:07 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: C:/texlive/2021
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022
```

## Update

I've run `tlmgr update -self` and it successful update. Next I've runed `tlmgr install polish` but it failed with error (i've cutted logs):

```
[Thu Jul 14 16:26:19 2022]   ERROR: latex.fmt/pdftex latex-dev.fmt/pdftex pdflatex-dev.fmt/pdftex pdftex.fmt/pdftex etex.fmt/pdftex pdfetex.fmt/pdftex
[Thu Jul 14 16:26:19 2022] running fmtutil-sys --byhyphen "language.dat.lua" --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\oFcnh67OIf\YWvlpiH6xf
[Thu Jul 14 16:26:24 2022] success, output:
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
```

After this update produce below:

```
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://repo.skni.umcs.pl/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2021/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr.pl: no self-updates for tlmgr available
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
```

Comment: well did you try `tlmgr update --self`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've run it and worked but now I have other problem. I'll update my question.